# Using psql option

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

```
#version: ppas 9.2
#pg_hba.conf

 local edb,testdb enterprisedb trust
 local edb user1 trust
 local edb user2 trust
 local all all md5
```

```
#pg_env.sh 
PGDATABASE=edb
```

When I type `psql`, I will connect to the `edb` database as an `enterprisedb` user without password.

But when I type `psql -h / tmp -U enterprisedb -l` it asks for a password, which means that `-h / tmp` connects locally.

Of course, I can run without password `psql -h /tmp -U enterprisedb -d edb -l` or `psql -h /tmp -U enterprisedb -c "\ l"` What's the difference?

The question is, what do you get the default value for when you run the `psql` command?
I want to run `psql -h / tmp -U enterprisedb -l` command without password.

Comment: It seems that `pg_env.sh` is not being pulled into your environment (maybe paste `env` output?).  If `PGDATABASE=edb` is in your environment, then `psql -U enterprisedb -l` will automatically use the `edb` database.  Also, if you are connecting to `localhost`, it might be less confusing to remove the `-h /tmp` flag

Answer (score 0):

when you type only "psql" it goes

> postgresql database with postgresql user

as default.

And in order to enter psql without password you can go pg_hba.conf and make your ip as trust instead of md5 or else.